# get s3 folder files using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

is there any way to get s3 specific folder all files keys which have a specific combination like

**But** I have a specific combination now in key like

```
 <transaction_id>/<this could be any thing>_input.json
```

I know transaction id but not sure the center part but it should  always end with `_input.json`  . how I can get keys of folder this way ?

Comment: Yes, call [ListObjectsv2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and provide the relevant prefix.

Comment: @jarmod can you please provide a small example of my case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list all objects with a common prefix with list_objects_v2.  From there you can filter out to only list items with a given suffix end string, or some other pattern:

```pythone
import boto3

bucket = "-example-bucket-"
prefix = "<transaction_id>/"
suffix = "_input.json"

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

# List all items that start with the prefix
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
    for cur in page.get("Contents", []):
        # And further filter to only items that end with the suffix
        if cur['Key'].endswith(suffix):
            # Just show the object's key
            print(cur['Key'])
```